# ASA firewall, Cisco AnyConnect VPN on Linux - fails with "AnyConnect package unavailable or corrupted"

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, anyconnect

AnyConnect works fine with Windows XP.

On Ubuntu Linux 9.10 32 bit, I downloaded anyconnect-linux-2.4.0202-k9.tar.gz, installed it, and tried to connect to the same ASA firewall. It failed with:

```
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
  >> error: AnyConnect package unavailable or corrupted. Contact your system administrator.
  >> notice: Connection attempt has failed.
  >> state: Disconnected
  >> state: Disconnected
```

Then I downloaded anyconnect-linux-2.4.0202-k9.pkg from cisco.com and installed it on the ASA's flash:

```
foobar# show flash
--#--  --length--  -----date/time------  path
   75  8192        Nov 12 2009 05:02:58  log
  154  4181246     Dec 31 2002 16:08:18  securedesktop-asa-3.2.1.103-k9.pkg
  155  398305      Dec 31 2002 16:08:40  sslclient-win-1.1.0.154.pkg
   79  8192        Oct 24 2009 13:15:24  crypto_archive
  157  13934592    Nov 12 2009 04:52:54  asa805-k8.bin
  158  11491880    Nov 12 2009 04:56:48  asdm-623.bin
  159  3191813     Nov 12 2009 06:41:18  anyconnect-win-2.4.0202-k9.pkg
  164  5199492     Nov 24 2009 13:58:12  anyconnect-linux-2.4.0202-k9.pkg

255426560 bytes total (216465408 bytes free)
```

Tried again with Linux - fails exactly the same way. The ASA log says:

```
Group <DfltGrpPolicy> User <foo> IP <X.Y.Z.K> WebVPN session terminated: User Requested.
```

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, my mistake.

It's not enough to upload the package to the ASA flash, you have to actually declare it in the config as an AnyConnect image file, otherwise it won't work.

[Configuring the Security Appliance to Download the AnyConnect Client](http://cisco.com/en/US/customer/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect24/administration/guide/ac02asaconfig.html#wp1059416)

Comment: This link does not require log-in: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect24/administration/guide/ac02asaconfig.html